# pass the dropdown value into controller with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have search many time in google but i did not find my a answers.
I have one Select html tag that it have 3 option tag . i want pass these select value with Jquery Ajax but I cant .

This is my Html tag

```
     <select id="discount" onchange="discountPostback()" title="">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0">نمایش کل </option>
        <option value="1">نمایش افراد با تخفیف</option>
        <option value="2">نمایش افراد بدون تخفیف</option>


    </select>
```

javascript

```
   function discountPostback() {
            debugger;


                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Index","Report")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { type: $('discount').val },
                    success: function () {

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
                return false;
        }
```

MVC Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(short? type)
```

How can i just pass the value ? nothing more

Comment: data: { type: $('#discount').val() } <- That should do it. You where missing the `#` identifier in your selector that makes it look for an ID, and .val() is a `jQuery` method that will return the `select`'s  selected value.

Comment: What do you mean by "Nothing more" ?

Comment: @ Karim BENHDECH i mean that i want just to pass the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only a couple of things wrong with your code. See the working example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#discount').on('change', function() {
    alert($('#discount').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="discount" onchange="discountPostback()" title="">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="0">نمایش کل</option>
  <option value="1">نمایش افراد با تخفیف</option>
  <option value="2">نمایش افراد بدون تخفیف</option>
</select>
```

You need to select the select using the ID which requires the `#` in your selector, and `val()` is the `jQuery` method to get the select's value and nothing else as shown below.

**Fix**

```
$('#discount').val()
```

**Further Reading**

[jQuery .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

[jQuery ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#discount").val()
```

return the value of selected option

```
$("#discount").text()
```

return the text of selected option

I think that you want

Answer (score 1):

From jQuery Ajax add the below line

```
$('#discount option:selected').val();
```

You can print those values from the selected drop-down list by adding
these below lines above the Ajax i.e, from JavaScript

```
var discount = $('#discount option:selected').val();
console.log(discount);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try This

 function discountPostback() {
            debugger;


                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Index","Report")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: '{ type: $('#discount').val() }',
                    success: function () {

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
                return false;
        }
```